# Blender stopped responding

Tags: physics

I was modeling a planet and I went to physics option after that I clicked on soft body option and blender stopped responding. Please help

Comment: how much ram do you have? have you needed to force quit blender before?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE!! Tech support and/or bug reports are beyond the scope of this site. You'll have much better luck in a BlenderArtists forum

Answer (score 1):

This rarely works as expected, but you can try to recover work by going to File> Recover Last Session.

Comment: You can also try File>Recover Auto Save. This works best if you have set Blender to auto save every minute, or it won't do much...